# Using a list with words to find that words in a text

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list with words and want to search that words in a text. My list looks like:

`split_list = [y for x in old_list for y in x.split()]
set_list = list(set(split_list))
['Hello', 'Welcome', 'World'] #this is how the list looks like`

Now I want to take that set_list and search the text with all words in that list. What I tried:

`words_text = set(set_list).intersection(the_text)
print words_text`

I only get the set_list printed. What did I miss? If the set_list has the word “Hello”, i need all “Hello” that are in the text in a new list. Like: ['Hello', 'Hello', 'Welcome', 'Hello', ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set intersection only returns the *set* of words that are in common. Each word is only listed once (because that's what being in a set means).

To list words multiple times, try:

```
[word for word in the_text.split() if word in set_list]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. But its weird, i dont get all. I got 26 from a word that is 41 times in the text.

Comment: There could be explanations for that. For example, if you're searching for `"Hello"` and your text contains `"Hello,World"` with no space, then the "Hello" won't be found because `.split()` only splits on spaces and you are comparing complete words. Also, uppercase and lowercase are considered different unless you want to treat them the same. So `"Hello"` will not match `"hello"`.

Comment: Yep, the comma. And there are some with a point after. Okay, so i only have to get rid of the punctuation in the text, right? Like: `punctuation=re.compile(r"[-.?!,:;()0-9\n\r|]")
text_punct=[punctuation.sub("", word) for word in the_text]`

Comment: Well that will do something, and it might be what you want. Hard for me to say. :)

Comment: Its not working. :) But i will find a solution to get rid of the punctuation of the_text. It cant be that hard...